# Application : Is there a way to save and close external file without prompt?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a macro to open a Resource Pool, extract resources data and import to an excel workbook then open a second workbook with actual employee list, compare and mix both lists and inject complete updated list to MSP resource pool.

Everything works but I get the annoying MSP Save As prompt window at the end of the process.

I tried all `ProjApp.DisplayAlerts = False`, `ProjApp.FileCloseEx`, `ProjApp.FileCloseEx pjSave`, `ProjApp.FileExit`, `ProjApp.FileExit pjSave` or `ProjApp.ActiveProject.SavesAs ProjApp.ActiveProject.Name` but I always have this prompt window which I'd like to get rid of. Is there any way to do so, just like for Excel Workbooks?

Edit :
It seems like the issue comes from the FileOpenEx method. I set `ProjApp.FileOpenEx(file, False, , , , , , , , , , 2)` but when it come to FileCloseEx I get a message that file is Read Only and not Read/Write as it is supposed to be

```
Dim ProjApp As MSProject.Application
Dim Proj As MSProject.Project

Set ProjApp = GetX("MSProject.Application")
ProjApp.Visible = True
ProjApp.DisplayAlerts = False

If ProjApp.FileOpenEx(files.MSPResourcePool, False, , , , , , , , , , 2) Then
    Set Proj = ProjApp.ActiveProject
Else
    MsgBox "Fichier non trouvé : " & vbCrLf & files.MSPRessPool
    Exit Sub
End If

ProjApp.ViewApplyEx Name:="Resource Sheet", ApplyTo:=0

...

ProjApp.FileCloseEx
Set Proj = Nothing
Set ProjApp = Nothing

ProjApp.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: If you do these steps manually, the Resource Pool file is opened read-write or read-only?

Comment: It opens in read only. I suspect it is due to the fact that it actually is a Resource Pool and hence could be protected in some way. I will try to open the Master Planning with Resource Pool and see if it changes anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening both the Resources pool *AND* the Master Planning seems to do the trick. Had to change closing method as well from `ProjApp.FileCloseEx`to `ProjApp.Quit pjSave`

```
Dim ProjApp As MSProject.Application
Dim Proj As MSProject.Project

Set ProjApp = GetX("MSProject.Application")
ProjApp.Visible = True
ProjApp.DisplayAlerts = False

    If ProjApp.FileOpenEx(files.MSPRessPool, False, , , , , , , , , , 3) Then
        Set Proj = ProjApp.ActiveProject
    Else
        MsgBox "Fichier non trouvé : " & vbCrLf & files.MSPRessPool
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If ProjApp.FileOpenEx(files.MasterPlanning, False, , , , , , , , , , 3) Then
        Set Proj = ProjApp.ActiveProject
    Else
        MsgBox "Fichier non trouvé : " & vbCrLf & files.MSPRessPool
        Exit Sub
    End If

ProjApp.ViewApplyEx Name:="Resource Sheet", ApplyTo:=0

...

ProjApp.Quit pjSave
Set Proj = Nothing
Set ProjApp = Nothing

ProjApp.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Now I update the resources in the Master Planning and it updates the resources in Resources Pool.

Another option I would have like to use would have been `ProjApp.ResourceSharingPoolUpdate` but 1/ it does not work when the Resources Pool is open with read/write rights and 2/ it says that Resources Pool is read only if open like this and ask to save as a copy. Guess I still have some work to master those mysteries :)